# Entity Framework performance degradation

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have a ridiculously simple edmx model, with one database and one entity for one database table. Testing sequential retrieval of all records from a local virtual database server.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System.Diagnostics;

    private static readonly ConcurrentBag<long> Stats = new ConcurrentBag<long>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            using (var ctx = new ScratchEntities())
            {
                foreach (var invoice in ctx.Invoices.Select(
                    s => new
                         {
                             s.Id,
                             s.Amount,
                             s.DueDate
                         }))
                {

                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Stats.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Min {0}    Max {1}    Avg {2}", Stats.Min(), Stats.Max(), Stats.Average());

    }
}
```

Under EF 4 and 5, it took around 2-2.5s to execute. Upgraded to Nuget's EF6, almost 10s.

On a similar note, it also takes 4-5 times as long when I use foreach over ctx.Invoices, as compared to foreach over ctx.Invoices.Select(s=>new{all columns here}).

Puzzled.

**UPDATE:**

Iterating 5 times

**EF 6.0.1**  Min 3082    Max 9231    Avg 4462.8

**EF 5.0.0**  Min 1502    Max 2016    Avg 1665.4

All times in milliseconds for 1M rows.

.Net 4.5

**UPDATE 2:**

Discarding first five tests out of a 105

**EF 6.0.1** Min 2698    Max 4383    Avg 3136

**EF 5.0.0** Min 1426    Max 2922    Avg 1628

**UPDATE 3:**

After recreating TT templates per advise [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469466)

**EF 6.0.1** Min 2589    Max 4279    Avg 3027

After compiling EF6 with NGEN described [**here**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/10/17/ef6-rtm-available.aspx)

**EF 6.0.1** Min 2644    Max 4322    Avg 3045.7

**UPDATE 4:**

After changing to AsEnumerable

**EF 6.0.1** Min 2661    Max 4658    Avg 3134.6

Comment: Benchmark it twice (in the same app domain/process). The first time a context is created there's a bunch of housekeeping that needs doing.

Comment: I did. Multiple times. Meaning, I ran the app a few times, recording runtimes. Upgraded, then ran it a bunch of times again. Even took it as far as creating same program from scratch. EF5 2.5s the most, EF6, 8.9s minimum. I will redo with the same app using a simple loop.

Comment: *Meaning, I ran the app a few times* This is benchmarking across multiple processes. Or, more importantly, multiple app domains.

Comment: Well it seems like EF6 is slower. Could I bother you to test 1000 times in the one process and discard the first 5 results? Discarding the first result would be to get the behind-the-scenes stuff all prepared and then that plus the other four are to warm up SQL Server's caches. And I take it this is in Release mode, without the debugger attached (i.e. "push CTRL+F5"). It might also be interesting to use the context 1, 10 and 100 times during each loop (e.g. just repeat your `foreach` `x` times)

Comment: instead of `.Select` does `.AsEnumerable` or `.ToList` have any performance implications?

Comment: Will check AsEnumerable but ToList would materialize this whole thing into memory.

Comment: I work on the EF team as Microsoft. Couple of things to check. 
Are you running with the debugger attached? If so, there is a known issue that we are working on a fix for at the moment - http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1778. 
Can you also confirm that you have the 6.0.1 version of the NuGet package. There were some other perf issues in 6.0.0 that we fixed in the 6.0.1 patch release.
If neither of these are the case would it be possible to get a copy of your EDMX file so that we can find out what is causing the slow performance.

Comment: No debugger attached. Release mode with Ctrl+F5. ZIP archive with EDMX posted to https://www.cubby.com/pl/Cubby.Public/_cfc3488d84b54a32873cbc69f56bc76c

Comment: Thank you for confirming and providing the repro. I've opened an item in our tracking system and someone from our team will investigate - https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1786.

BTW we are putting together a 6.0.2 patch release with performance fixes at the moment - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/10/31/ef6-performance-issues.aspx.

Comment: @RowanMiller I saw your article and came here to post it. But you've beaten me to it. Thanks for all your work on EF.

Comment: Hi Darek. How many invoices are there in your database? Sorry if you already provided that information and I am missing it.

Comment: There are exactly one million invoices. The entities need not be tracked. But the post is not about EF performance in general, just about degradation in EF 6.

Answer (score 3):

In EF6 we changed the default data retrieval behavior from streaming to buffering (see [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Connection%20Resiliency%20Spec) for why). Buffering adds additional overhead, which is particularly visible when executing no-tracking queries such as projections into unmapped CLR types or via the AsNoTracking extension method. To alleviate the issue, we added the **AsStreaming** extension method that turns off buffering on a per-query basis. Using AsStreaming should give you EF5 like performance.

Comment: AsStreaming is deprecated now. I assume in EF6 performance is back to EF5 level without AsStreaming.